# How do I add elements from one array to an empty array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been stuck trying to add some elements from one array to another. I have an array with two attributs name and image but I only want to add all the image elements to an empty array. How could I do that ?

```
    let characters = [
    {
    name: "character1",
    img: "image/character1.png"
   },
   {
    name: "character2",
    img: "image/character2.png"
   },
   {
    name: "character3",
    img: "image/character3.png"
   },
   {
    name: "character4",
    img: "image/character4.png"
   }
]     
let newArray = [];
```

Comment: `let newArray = characters.map(e => e.img);`

Comment: a for loop or map as the above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use array.map function to create a new array from an array of objects.

```
let characters = [{
        name: "character1",
        img: "image/character1.png"
    },
    {
        name: "character2",
        img: "image/character2.png"
    },
    {
        name: "character3",
        img: "image/character3.png"
    },
    {
        name: "character4",
        img: "image/character4.png"
    }
]
let newArray = characters.map(o => o.img);
console.log(newArray);
```

Output:

```
[
  'image/character1.png',
  'image/character2.png',
  'image/character3.png',
  'image/character4.png'
]
```